# Given a WPF Image control, is it possible to determine its HWND?

Tags: c#, wpf, directshow, directshow.net

I am integrating a webcam in a WPF application. I can see the camera feed in the main window, as I pass its HANDLE on to the DirectShow functions. But this is not what I want.

The main form has a Image control, where I'd like to see the output. However, in order to do this, I need the control's Handle.

Any hint on how to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Gianluca.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An [Image Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) in WPF, unlike Windows Forms, doesn't actually have an HWND.

WPF works differently than Windows Forms - each control is not a wrapper around a native "window" with a handle, but rather composed together using Direct3D at runtime by the layout system.

If you need to actually host output from a Webcam inside of a WPF window, you should look at using [HwndHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndhost.aspx) (or a subclass).  The simplest way is often to just host a Windows Forms control inside of a [WindowsFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx), though managing an HWND yourself via `HwndHost` is more efficient.

Comment: thank you! I am now trying to use the WindowsFormsHost but apparently nothing is displayed. I'm working on it and I'll let you know! Thank you again!

Comment: @Gianluca: You'll need to put a control inside the WindowsFormsHost - I recommend putting a Windows.Forms.Panel there - then use the panel's Handle as your HWND.

Answer (score 0):

Using an WindowsFormsHost and a picture box inside is a good solution that I used for a similar problem where I needed a handle to display a video stream. But be careful, in order to work, the Window that is hosting the WindowsFormsHost control must have AllowsTransparency="false"!